# My custom native module is not present inside NativeModules object

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-native-module

So, i wanted to create a native module which will detect, if the app is running on emulator/simulator or an actual device.

Everything works fine on android, but i'm facing issue on iOS.

I have create a AbcModule.h and a AbcModule.m file

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
@interface AbcModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

This is AbcModule.h

```
#import "AbcModule.h"

@implementation AbcModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(GetDetails);

- (BOOL) xyzFunctn {
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        return YES;
    #else
        return NO;
    #endif
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(xyzFunctn: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    resolve self.xyzFunctn;
}

@end
```

This is AbcModule.m

Here i have followed the react native documentation for implementing the Native Modules.

But i'm consistently facing this error which says
"TypeError null is not an object, evaluating GetDetails.xyzFunctn"

I have went through several solutions and articles but nothing seems to be working here.

Need help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if there is someone who is facing this issue and feels like their code should work but it isn't and any solution online not working for you as well.

Try this:
When you create your .h and .m file for header and objective-c or swift file, make sure you do it in Xcode and not from VSCode.

VSCode eventually doesn't adds you .h file in the required resources folder, i have wasted my 2 weeks trying to find out solution for it, but lastly, that was it, yes this is it.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs

> If you do not specify a name, the JavaScript module name will match the Objective-C class name, with any "RCT" or "RK" prefixes removed.

so just do not specify any name,

```
@implementation AbcModule

// To export a module named AbcModule
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

@end
```

in your case it should then be accessible from within JS with
`AbcModule`

But the documentation is not clear if the Objective-C Class declaration needs to be written with prefixed "RCT" or "RK".. but because both prefixes seem to be valid, you should be able to just use `AbcModule` without prefix.

In other words, if you want to use `GetDetails` from within JS you need to name your interface and implementation accordingly

```
@implementation RCTGetDetails
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(GetDetails);
// or
// RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

in your .m file, let's say GetDetails is a class of NSObject .swift
you need:

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(WidgetManager, NSObject)
// method to export
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(isAuthenticated: (BOOL *)isAuthenticated)
@end
```

in your GetDetails.swift:

```
@objc(GetDetails)
class GetDetails: NSObject {

@objc(isAuthenticated:)
  func isAuthenticated(_ isAuthenticated: Bool) {
}
}
```